# Why don't images use functions to store rgb values?

Tags: rgb

Today I was wondering why are rgb values stored in files at all? Wouldn't it save space if a program could take rgb values and develop a function for each color: r(x) g(x), b(x)? I would assume it would be costly at run time to iterate through the function a few million times but the trade off would be no file size. Clearly i'm missing something and would really appreciate an explanation for why this isn't feasible thanks.

Comment: And how would those functions work?  How would it now what value to return for a certain x (and shouldn't that be x,y as pictures usually have two dimensions).  I think you are thinking of image compression of which there are various ones around e.g. JPG, PNG etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a way you are right, it is inefficient to store the RGB values for every pixel (aka a bitmap), thats why many formats such as png use compression (jpeg uses lossy compression which saves even more memory). However you are mistaken that you can simply create a simple function that will tell you the value of every pixel at a certain point. You could of course construct such a function,say a polynomial, for an arbitrary image, but this function would have so many terms that you wouldn't really save any memory, because you still need to store the function. There is a fundamental limit to how much you can compress an image or any data, which depends on the entropy.

If you are interested in that sort of thing, look up "Fractal Compression" or "Lossless compression (section: Limitations)" on Wikipedia.